# Unable to click link text element in selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

HTML:

```
  td class="tab"><a href="../accountopening/displayintroducer.jsp" target="mainFrame">Introducer</a> </td>
```

Tried with below locators

```
linktext=Introducer, partialinktext 

xpath =("//a[href*='../accountopening/displayintroducer.jsp']");
```

Comment: any exception did you facing?

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this XPATH...

```
//a[contains(@href,’../accountopening/displayintroducer.jsp’)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

Try the following `xpath`s:

```
"//a[contains(text(),'Introducer')]"
```

> OR

```
"//a[contains(@href,'accountopening/displayintroducer.jsp')]"
```

> OR

```
"//a[contains(text(),'Introducer')][contains(@href,'accountopening/displayintroducer.jsp')]"
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Answer (score 0):

You xpath appears wrong to me.

Try below xpath :-

```
//a[contains(.,'Introducer')]
```

OR

```
//a[@href='../accountopening/displayintroducer.jsp']
```

OR (More specific)

```
//a[contains(.,'Introducer') and @target='mainFrame']
```

Hope it will help you :)